# Can prerender.io help for situations like dynamic seo for a front end route with dynamic parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, frontend, googlebot, prerender

The detailed problem can be found on this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36931309/dynamic-seo-for-routes-in-angular2any-frontend-routing-framework?noredirect=1#comment61422672_36931309

My situation is - I have a front end route /category/:categoryId. This categoryId could be different and accordingly I fetch different data from server. This data contains the title that I should set for this page.

Now doing SEO for different categoryId in this case seems impossible from frontend as google bot won't wait for my server response while crawling.

Can prerender solve this particular situation and how? I have never used prerender.io. My backend is written in ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! Prerender loads your pages in a browser just like a user would and then saves the resulting HTML to serve back to the crawlers. That way you can dynamically load content, or even dynamically tell us to return a 301/404 to the crawlers based on the content.